# Manipulating strings of multibyte characters

Tags: c++, c, string

I am a novice C programmer. I am trying to write a C program which sometimes deals with English text (fits into 8-bit chars) and sometimes Japanese text (needs 16 bits).

Do I need to set aside 16 bits for every character, even the English text if I use the same code to manipulate either country's text?

What are some of the ways of encoding multibyte characters?

What if the compiler can't store multibyte strings compactly?

I'm confused. Please help me out here. Kindly, support your answers with code examples. Also, please explain the same with context of C++ as I am learning C++ also & have beginner-level experience in this language too.

Thanks in advance.

**This was a interview question asked to one of my acquaintance a few days back.**

Comment: which SDK you are using Visual Studio?

Comment: UTF-8 is the way to go.

Comment: @JimBalter: for input and output, absolutely. For intermediate handling, surely full 16-bit is more convenient? Working in UTF8 makes all basic string handling way more complicated.

Comment: @Jongware If you can 100% guarantee that 16 bits will always be enough for you, probably. But if your text can possibly (now or in the future) contain surrogate pairs (two consecutive 16-bit chars making up one code point), you're better off with UTF-8, because **1.** you'll only be paying storage when you need it, **2.** you'll have to deal with multichar encoding anyway, and **3.** quite a lot 3rd party 16-bit routines do not handle surrogate pairs correctly, while multichar is generally better implemented in UTF-8 handling.

Comment: @Angew I agree with you.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: While we're sharing links, another related read: [UTF-8 everywhere](http://www.utf8everywhere.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can use `std::wstring` which uses `wchar_t` as the underlying `char` type. In C++11 you can also use `std::u16string` or `std::u32string` depending on the amount of storage for a character you need.

C also have `wchar_t` defined in `<wchar.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after doing a little bit of research, I think I got an answer:

mbstowcs ("multibyte string to wide character string") and wcstombs ("wide character string to multibyte string") convert between arrays of wchar_t (in which every character takes 16 bits, or two bytes) and multibyte strings (in which individual characters are stored in one byte if possible).